# How is Nick still alive?

Tags: supernatural

This question is about the story as shown in *Supernatural* Season 14.

We know that Castiel's vessel Jimmy Novak died when Castiel was killed the first time. Castiel also mentions this a few times during the course of the series (for example, "Gods and Monsters", Season 14). Similarly, I assumed Lucifer's vessel Nick was also dead. In the episode "Swan Song", Season 5, he is pretty dead when Lucifer leaves him to possess Sam, although later on, Crowley's minions discover the body, "spruce it up" and make it better habitable for Lucifer. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/Supernatural/comments/7xxpqf/spoilers_lucifers_nick_vessel_theory/dudyvuw) subreddit seems to agree with me.

However, in Season 14 now, we see Nick is alive and trying to kill the murderer of his wife and baby,

> and even supposedly *reviving* Lucifer,

even after Lucifer was killed by Michael with an angel blade at the end of Season 13.

So how did Nick come back to life even though Jimmy remained dead? Is it an effect of the demon blood Lucifer drank so that Nick's body could sustain him?

Comment: How is *Supernatural* still alive? ;)

Comment: Probably the better question to ask. xD

Comment: Interesting question, but my guess is it will be answered in a future episode.

Comment: This confused me as well. Plus, if this revival thing is legit, it is possible to bring back all the archangels right?

Comment: @RakihthaRR well, it _seems_ Gabriel's vessel is dead for him to pray for Gabriel to return, and most of Gabriel's grace is lost on Jack as well, from what I gather of the last episode...

Comment: Seems like that. But Lucifer's grace too must have been destroyed when he was killed.

Comment: I've edited out the last paragraph as that seemed to be asking a separate question, if you still want to ask please feel free to ask it as a new question. Alternatively if I'm wrong and it is related to this question please edit it back in.